# .net c# datetimepicker text is null on tabpage

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, tabpage

I have a Visual Studio 2012 WindForm App.

I have an form with three tabpages.

I have a datetimePicker in one TabPage.

I assign a valid date to the datepicker.

```
  datePicker.Text = "10/10/2015";
```

But, when I run the App, if i never set focus on that tab, the datetimepicker.Text is always null

How can i solve this?

Comment: Have you try to set it's `Value` property instead?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Value` property of your `DateTimePicker` instead of `Text`:

```
datePicker.Value = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10);
...
var selectedDate = datePicker.Value;
```